# Virtualbox: print from Windows XP guest in Xubuntu host, using NAT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, printing

I have several network printers at work and at home I'd like to access in a Windows XP guest, under a Xubuntu 12.04 host.  I have networking set to NAT, since I take my laptop back and forth to work and the IP address changes every day.

I've tried [these instructions](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=4995#p4995), but my CUPS error log has the following line:

```
Request from "localhost" using invalid Host: field "10.0.2.2:631"
```

Is there something simple I'm doing wrong?